# How to Export Data Structure from Aginity workbench for Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aginity

1. I am trying to compare data structure from Toad for Oracle(Connected to SAP BO) and Aginity Workbench for Redshift.
2. I am unable to find a way to export the data structure from Aginity Workbench for Redshift to excel.
3. Finally, I want to export all the tables, Columns and data type of those columns in an excel file so I can compare the two data structures.

Thanks in Advance
Samir

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to export data structure from Aginity workbench for Redshift. 
1. Right click on table name
2. Select Script -> DDL to Clipboard
3. Paste the output in Text file.

Still looking for a way to export the structure in Excel but this also helps in comparing.